# How to stop CSS selector from selecting all child elements

Tags: html, css

I have a list with some nested lists inside it like this:

```
<ul class="menuSports">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<ul>
```

and am using a before element to create an arrow so that the items are displayed like a dropwdown list:

```
#menuSports li ul li:before { content: '\25BA'; position:absolute; color:#cecece; padding-left: 5px; padding-top:5px;}
```

The problem is the before element is being applied to all li elements from the one specified onwards, kind of like this:

```
#menuSports li ul li:before { content: '\25BA'; position:absolute; color:#cecece; padding-left: 5px; padding-top:5px;}
#menuSports li ul li ul li:before { content: '\25BA'; position:absolute; color:#cecece; padding-left: 5px; padding-top:5px;}
```

Is there a way to stop this from happening, so that only the li specified in the first selector is given the element?

P.S I can not change the html code or use javascript, using css is my only option.

Comment: Just use the > for selecting the nested element. That way you will locate only the nested in this iten, not all of them. Something like this - '#menuSports>ul>li'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ul li { margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
ul > li { margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
```

The first selector above is a decendant selector. It will select any list items that are anywhere underneath an unordered list in the markup structure. The list item could be buried three levels deep within other nested lists, and this selector will still match it.

The second selector above is a child combinator selector. This means it will only select list items that are direct children of an unordered list. In otherwords, it only looks one level down the markup structure, no deeper. So if there was another unordered list nested deeper, the list item children of it will not be targeted by this selector.

For more information try this **[link](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can specify level(s) of `LI` using `descendant` selector.

So,

```
#menuSports > li {/* only first level LIs */}
#menuSports > li > ul > li {/* only second level LIs */}
#menuSports > li > ul > li > ul > li {/* only third level LIs */}
```

Alternative is to reset styles for next levels

```
#menuSports li li:before {content: 'content'; /* second and each nest level LIs */}
#menuSports li li li li:before {content: ''; /* fourth and each next are reseted */}
```